# Validating data in Firebase - Duplicades in documents

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does anyone know if there is in Firebase any method created to avoid duplicity of data? For example, in the data collection can not exist more than one document with the same email, phone number and identification personal.

I did these validations in a crude way, without having knowledge that there is something already pre-developed for this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing provided.  Your code has to define what "duplicate" means and enforce it.  The only thing the database will do is ensure that all child keys with the same parent are unique.

Comment: Thanks Doug for this response!